# WebApi Helppage Description Column

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Just want to ask where to put the "Description" remarks so it can comes up when my colleague see in the help page?

I have tried in ViewModel using triple slash summary also try to put in Display Attribute with no lucks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please fill up the summary part of the comment on the property in your model for that to come up on the API help page.
I am attaching pics :

[image]

Which shows up as :

[image]

Comment: it works for the first one but if it is reference to complex Object, eventhough i add summary description..it still not show up